# Model comparison for regression: significant gain in rmse

Tags: regression, predictive-models, model-comparison

I am comparing the predictive power of two regression models. RMSE gain is $13\%$ using a full model compared to reduced one on the test set. I do not want to compromise on model complexity hence wondering if $13\%$ is significant enough to use full model.

Correction: RMSE for full model is $.13$ whereas for reduced one is $.15$. Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the two models are nested, you should run an F-test.

Comment: Full model have 5 extra variables compared to the reduced one. So yes they are nested. Is there any other test that I should run as well?

Comment: No other test. F-test will answer your exact question: which of the two models is preferable. Of course, the assumptions have to be met. Either normality of residuals or sufficiently large sample size.

Comment: The anova turned out to be insignificant but the shapiro-wilk suggest residuals are not normally distributed. The sample size is 1164. Would it be significantly large to choose the reduced model? Btw are you referring to testing set sample size or total sample size?

Comment: I'm referring to the number of observations that were used in fitting the full model. If such a number is close to 1164, asymptotic normality is the case due to the effect of the Central Limit Theorem. So the F-test is valid and you should opt for the reduced model.

Comment: What if the number of observations are 240? Could you share some referrences for the asymptotic normality assumption?

Comment: The number variables are 9 in the reduced model.

Comment: Depends on the distribution of residuals. You can follow the F-test with a randomization test and see if the two agree.

Comment: What if data distribution is assumed to be nonparqmeteric? What test then needs to be performed?

Comment: Randomization test.

Comment: Conventionally RMSE stands for "root mean squared error". So the bigger model uses 5 more predictors to end up with higher prediction error? I'm not sure why you refer to this as "gain".

Comment: @dipetkov thanks for pointing out. I made the correction to the original post. RMSE for the full model is smaller than the reduced one. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Where did you edit @ArtiThakur?

Comment: Did you propose the edit anonymously?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid model complexity? In other words, so what if the model with better performance has five additional variables?

Comment: @Dave thats a really good question I have been asking myself. I would choose model more parsimonious model in most cases. Though in this case, it is an exploratory analysis and for some DVs signals aren’t clear enough for me to identify most significant variables to keep. That is the reason I was wondering what are the traditional ways to identify model in such cases.

Comment: But why do you want model parsimony? Yes, throwing tons of variables at a problem until the fit is good does put you at a risk of overfitting, but that does not assure you of overfitting (and leaving out variables puts you at risk of underfitting). I’m not saying it’s wrong to seek model parsimony, but it is not obvious to me why it must be a goal.

Comment: Because the variables have to make sense theoretically as well. The goal is to find a model which is not only predictive but also explanatory in terms of explaining phenomenon in regards to the DV.

Comment: Do those five variables not make theoretical sense?